# Kinect: From Color Space to world coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, kinect

I am tracking a ball using the rgb data from kinect. After this I look up the corresponding depth data. Both of this is working splendid. Now I want to have the actual x,y,z world coordinates (i.e skeleton Space) instead of the x_screen, y_screen and depth values. Unfortunately the methods given by the kinect sdk (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) don`t help me. Basically i need a function "NuiImageGetSkeletonCoordinatesFromColorPixel" but i does not exist. All the functions basically go in the opposite direction

I know this can probably be done with openNI but i can not use it for other reasons.

Is there a function that does this for me or do i have to do the conversion myself? If I have to do it myself, how would i do this? I sketched up a little diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCl7X.png - do you think this would work?

Comment: Why does [`NuiTransformDepthImageToSkeleton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663871.aspx) not work for you?

Comment: I track using color. So i have x,y in "rgb-space". I then transform my depth data to rgb space using another sdk function :NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution to look up the corresponding depth value. Unfortunately there is no inverse of this function so i have no way to go back to depth space. But for NuiTransformDepthImageToSkeleton i need x,y in depth space :(

[EDIT]: Or is this actually just a misconception of mine? When they say "The x-coordinate of the depth pixel." in the documentation, do they actually mean the x,y in RGB space?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood... I would see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902593/get-depth-at-color-position-kinect-sdk) as it sounds exactly like what you want

Answer (score 3):

Check the CameraIntrinsics.

```
typedef struct _CameraIntrinsics
{
    float FocalLengthX;
    float FocalLengthY;
    float PrincipalPointX;
    float PrincipalPointY;
    float RadialDistortionSecondOrder;
    float RadialDistortionFourthOrder;
    float RadialDistortionSixthOrder;
}   CameraIntrinsics;
```

You can get it from `ICoordinateMapper::GetDepthCameraIntrinsics`.

Then, for every pixel `(u,v,d)` in depth space, you can get the coordinate in world space by doing this:

```
x = (u - principalPointX) / focalLengthX * d;
y = (v - principalPointY) / focalLengthY * d;
z = d;
```

For color space pixel, you need to first find its associated depth space pixel, which you should use `ICoordinateMapper::MapCameraPointTodepthSpace`. Since not all color pixel has its associated depth pixel (1920x1080 vs 512x424), you can't have the full-HD color point cloud.