# Obtain realworld (X, Y, Z) coordinates from Xbox One Kinect

Tags: c#, coordinates, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using an Xbox One Kinect to track an object, I'm currently able to obtain the objects Z coordinate (distance from the Kinect in mm) using the depth image. The goal is to be able to also obtain the realworld X and Y coordinates in mm as well. How would I go about that?

I've used the math from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832238/kinect-intrinsic-parameters-from-field-of-view/18199938#18199938), with the Xbox One Kinects FOV #'s, but it doesn't come out right.

Comment: How exactly is it wrong? You have not given us much to go on here

Comment: It's just off, slightly to the side.

Comment: MY question is more or less this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417495/how-to-get-real-world-coordinates-x-y-z-from-a-distinct-object-using-a-kinec

Comment: After more searching I found the answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579552/kinect-from-color-space-to-world-coordinates?rq=1)!

Answer (score 0):

Now only with the Depth stream you cannot do it. You need to identify the edges using the gray scale image. The same object has the same gray color value so that just by getting the color change you can pin point the edges of the objects. Like this you can calculate the edges and then take x, y points of that object.